# React-native android build error : Cannot invoke method mavenDeployer() on null object (line 131)

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

Add repositories.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

---

```
    task installArchives(type: Upload) {
        configuration = configurations.archives
        repositories.mavenDeployer { // line 131
            // Deploy to react-native-event-bridge/maven, ready to publish to npm
            repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven"
            configureReactNativePom pom
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how I can fix it. Please help me. If you guys need more information let me know and I will add more.

I did try to change some lines in `repositories.mavenDeployer` but it didn't work. I got same messages when I did something.

Comment: Looks like `repositories` is null. Where is it defined and what does it contain?

Comment: i upload repositories. Do i miss something? it is defined same file.

Answer (score 2):

```
task installArchives(type: Upload) {
 configuration = configurations.archives
 repositories{
     mavenDeployer { 
     repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven"
     configureReactNativePom pom
 }}}
```